# Embedded jetty application not working from jar

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty

I have the following code:

```
    Server server = new Server(9090);

    final URL warUrl = Main.class.getClassLoader().getResource("com/domain/webapps/app");
    final String warUrlString = warUrl.toExternalForm();
    WebAppContext wac = new WebAppContext(warUrlString, "/app");

    server.setHandler(wac);
```

I have the `Main` class in the `com.domain` package.

The jsp's and html's are in the `com.domain.webapps.app` package.

When run inside Netbeans (or `java -cp <classpath> com.domain.Main` on the exploded jar) the application works perfectly.

If i run the jar (`java -jar app.jar`), the content of the `com.domain.webapps.app` gets extracted to `/tmp/Jetty_something/webapp/`, so the full path is `/tmp/Jetty_something/webapp/com/domain/webapps/app/`

But when i make a request for `http://localhost:9090/app/file.jsp`, Jetty tries to get the file from `/tmp/Jetty_something/webapp/file.jsp` (the wrong place :-( )

What can i do where ?

Jetty version is 6.1.26

Comment: **2019-06-28** Please take a look at this [answer,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12672684/starting-up-embedded-jetty-server-for-a-jar-file/56812485#56812485) for a possible solution.

Comment: Just tried your suggestion and the error is exactly the same

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2009/10/02/executable-wars-with-jetty/) article. The URL is detected by

```
ProtectionDomain protectionDomain = Start.class.getProtectionDomain();
URL location = protectionDomain.getCodeSource().getLocation();
```

This works for me in a `war` project and maybe also for your `jar` use case.