# Starting up embedded jetty server for a JAR file

Tags: java, web-applications, jetty, executable-jar, embedded-jetty

What I am trying to do, is to build an executable `JAR` file which will contain my project. I have included its dependencies right next to it, also in `JAR` files, so my directory listing looks something like this:

> ~/Projects/Java/web-app/out:
>
> web-app.jar
>
> dependency1.jar
>
> dependency2.jar
>
> dependency3.jar

I know and am sure that my problem does not arise from dependencies, as my application functions properly, right up to the moment I start up Jetty embedded.

The code I use to start Jetty is like this:

```
public class ServerExecutionGoal implements ExecutionGoal {    

    private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ServerExecutionGoal.class);    

    private WebAppContext getWebAppContext() throws IOException {    
        WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();    
        System.out.println("context = " + context);    
        context.setResourceBase(new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResource("classpath:/webapp").getURL().toExternalForm());    
        context.setContextPath("/");    
        context.setLogger(new StdErrLog());    
        return context;    
    }    

    @Override    
    public void execute(Map<String, Object> stringObjectMap) throws ExecutionTargetFailureException {    
        logger.info("Instantiating target server ...");    
        final Server server = new Server(8089);    
        final ContextHandlerCollection handlerCollection = new ContextHandlerCollection();    
        try {    
            handlerCollection.setHandlers(new Handler[]{new RequestLogHandler(), getWebAppContext()});    
        } catch (IOException e) {    
            throw new ExecutionTargetFailureException("Could not create web application context", e);    
        }    
        server.setHandler(handlerCollection);    
        try {    
            logger.info("Starting server on port 8089 ...");    
            server.start();    
            server.join();    
            logger.info("Server started. Waiting for requests.");    
        } catch (Exception e) {    
            throw new ExecutionTargetFailureException("Failed to properly start the web server", e);    
        }    
    }    

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionTargetFailureException {    
        new ServerExecutionGoal().execute(null);    
    }    

}
```

I can validate that the "webapp" folder gets relocated correctly inside my JAR to `/webapp`, and that when running the code through my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA 11) `context.setResourceBase(new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResource("classpath:/webapp").getURL().toExternalForm())` maps validly to the resource in question. Also, I can show that it resolves to something like:

```
jar:file:~/Projects/Java/web-app/out/web-app.jar!/webapp
```

and is accessible (I read it).

However, when I start my application's main method, and Jetty starts, on `http://localhost:8089` I get the following:

> HTTP ERROR: 503
>
> Problem accessing /. Reason:
>
> ```
> Service Unavailable
> ```
>
> ---
>
> Powered by Jetty://

Where am I going wrong?

I know that by setting "resourceBase" to "." the address "`http://localhost:8089`" will act as an interface to the location "`~/Projects/Java/web-app/out/`" where I can see a listing of all the `JAR` files, including the "`web-app.jar`", upon clicking on which I am offered to download it.

I have seen the following questions, and the answers do not apply:

1. [Embedded jetty application not working from jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329076/embedded-jetty-application-not-working-from-jar): I get NullPointerException since `Start.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource()` resolves to `null`.
2. [Embedded Jetty WebAppContext FilePermission issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599935/embedded-jetty-webappcontext-filepermission-issue): which not only isn't answered, but the situation clearly does not apply, as I do not have permission issues (the fact that I can get a file listing should prove that).
3. [embedding jetty server problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312130/embedding-jetty-server-problems): also unanswered, also not applicable as I don't have any dependency problems (as pointed out previously in my comments above).

I think that I should somehow enable Jetty to access the `/webapp` folder, which is located under my `src/main/resources/` directory and is bundled into my web application. Should I be forsaking a bundled web application and deploy the exploded context path to somewhere accessible by Jetty instead (this is not desirable at all as it poses a multitude of issues for me and my clients).

Comment: You could use context.setWar(...) with a WAR file. This would just add one file to your distribution.

Comment: I am also facing a similar issue .when the server is started from eclipse I am getting proper response for the request.But when run it from a jar file from cmd, i get 404.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Its probably a long shot after almost 7 years, but have you found the solution?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, if the `WebAppContext` of Jetty can be used with `PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver`!

In one of my projects I solved this problem by writing my own `javax.servlet.Filter`, which loads the requested resources by `Class#getResourceAsStream`. 
`Class#getResourceAsStream` reads resources from inside a jars as well as inside a resource path (e.g. maven).

Hope this tip is helpful for you, cheers
Thilo

Answer (score 0):

I believe, I faced a similar problem a couple months ago, I used Jetty v9.4.12.v20180830.

Here is my solution:

If you have the following generated JAR structure:

```
 app.jar
   +----- com /
   |        +--- ( classes ... )
   |
   +----- config /
   |        |
   |        +--- display.properties
   |
   +----- webapp /
            |
            +--- index.html
```

Then the following code will refer to the correct folder:

```
ServletContextHandler webappContext = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);  
URL webRootLocation = YourJettyStarterClass.class.getResource("/webapp/index.html");  
URI webRootUri = URI.create(webRootLocation.toURI().toASCIIString().replaceFirst("/index.html$", "/"));  
webappContext.setContextPath("/");
webappContext.setBaseResource(Resource.newResource(webRootUri));
webappContext.setWelcomeFiles(new String[] { "index.html" });
```

**The important part:**

```
URL webRootLocation = YourJettyStarterClass.class.getResource("/webapp/index.html");
```